# How to control url page with htaccess and get parameter in index

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How to control url page with htaccess and get parameter in index page but no showing "index" in url, for example:

```
1)mydomain is "papashop.com"

2).htaccess :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?var1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [L,QSA]

3)code at contact.php :
<a href="page-alfa">Page Alfa</a>   ==> www.papashop.com/page-alfa 

4)code at index.php :
<?php  
$idpage=$_GET['var1'];  
if($idpage != ''){
  echo 'show content from query string url';
}else{
  echo 'content normal from index web';
}
?>
```

Noted:

1)true: papashop.com/page-alfa => not working/page not found. (I want to like this)

2)false: papashop.com/index/page-alfa  => this is work at my code in index.php (But I don't want to be like this)

3)i don't have a page-alfa.php file just index.php and contact.php in control panel.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will route all requests to index.php.

1: papashop.com/page-alfa will be true
2: papashop.com/index/page-alfa will be true as well.

To get the requested url in your code, try this:

```
<?php

    $request_uri = trim(explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0], '/');
    $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    // JUST MORE EXAMPLE
    $   $requests = explode('/', $request_uri);

    if(empty($requests) || count($requests) == 0){
        // This is ordinary papashop.com. This is index page.
    } else {
        if($requests[0] == 'page-alfa'){
            // Show page alfa.
        } else if($requests[0] == 'contact' && $requests[1] == 'phone'){
            // URL is papashop.com/contact/phone 
        }
        // etc...
    }

?>
```

Update:
If you are on localhost, RewriteBase will be something like `/site_root/`

Comment: not working, always redirect to dashboard apache. =(

Comment: It looks like you are on localhost (XAMPP or WAMP etc.). I updated my answer to show how to fix that.